# What happens if a change the SIM card to my phone?

Tags: sim-card, 8.1-oreo, motorola-moto-g5s-plus

Will Android add the contacts of the new SIM card to my Google Account?
What else could happen?

Comment: If your contacts are in your Google account, just sync your Google account.

Comment: The Moto 5GS by default does not support saving contacts to the SIM, any contacts on the SIM are displayed in the contact list but unless you use a third party application you cannot save or move contacts to the SIM card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably have a different phone number, and possibly a different contract/data plan for your device. If your device is [SIM-locked](/tags/sim-unlocking/info), you might have no service at all (i.e. no calls, SMS, internet) if the SIM card is from the "wrong" provider.

Apart of that, nothing would happen: contacts on the SIM card are not synchronized with any account.